# GET Not Working With Alpha Characters

Tags: php, get

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I have a GET request that pulls results from mysql.

Why would it work for:

http://someurl.com/process.php?id=123456789

but not for:

http://someurl.com/process.php?id=A23456789

```
if ( isset($_GET['id']) ) {
$sql = <<< SQL
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `id` = $_GET[id]
SQL;

more code... }
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to process the variable.

Comment: probably u are doing casting of get data..

Comment: u are wide exposed to sql injection so start using PDO and the issue is for string data u need wrap with single quotes. U can do it for int also no harm in that.

Comment: Does A23456789 exist in the table? It might be working fine...

Comment: Abhik is correct, the string data needed to be wrapped in quotes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't not work. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: Not really an answer, is it.